# jquery function that load html code into a div and then load other content into div inside html loaded

Tags: jquery, function, callback, load

I'd like to know what's the way to load an html page (page1.html) into a div in webpage active (index.html) and then load another html page (page2.html) into a div that will be inside of page loaded (page1.html). I mean.

index.html

```
<div id="content"></div>
<a class="link" href="#">load</a>
```

script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.link').live('click', function() {
        $('#content').load('page1.html', function(){
            $('#content2').load('page2.html');
        });
    });
});
```

page1.html

```
<div id="content2"></div>
```

It's works fine for only 1 click, at the second click it loads page2.html for 0,5 seconds and then loads page1.html.

What's the problem ???

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure, your `Page2` does not have a redirection for `Page1`

Comment: This code works for me using the latest jQuery, check your jQuery version or report what version you are using and in what browser it doesn't work

Comment: Please prepare a test, don't wait for the community to hack through you web site and find a solution.

Comment: Christopher, I'll do it when I have time for this, aren't you?

Answer (score 1):

The approach you have taken feels wrong. If you have no choice but to populate the page using this multiple ajax request approach, try explicitly populating the content div with the data from page 1 first, before going on to populating content2. This will mean you can't use the .load selector, and will need to do a regular ajax request, eg:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.link').live('click', function() {

        $.ajax({
                url : 'page1.html',
                success: function(data){
                    $('#content').html(data);
                    $('#content2').load('page2.html');
                    }
                });
    });
});
```

Comment: still having the same problem, but it's useful to apply this ajax method. Thank you

Comment: @GrahamB- he's using success callback of first load to call the second, so your solution is doing the same thing

Comment: I made a little sample app and got both my way and interestingly, your original way to work no problem, so I think something else is going on, can you extract the exact code from your site you are using and post an example on jsfiddle? You will have to mock the html responses using $.post so its not an exact replicate unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Using your code samples I can not reproduce the error -or I should call it "bug"?- using jQuery 1.6.4 on Chrome, Firefox and even IE8.

What I noticed is a unexpected behavior with Browser cache enabled. Source changes made on `Page1.html` where not fetched from server after the very first click on the link. I would recommend you to disable browser cache with Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools and do your tests again.

Also, please try with an updated version of jQuery, or at least the same version I'm using from http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js.

Is any of the above does not work, try to set a delay to fetch `page2.html`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.link').live('click', function() {
        $('#content').load('page1.html', function(){
            setTimeout("$('#content2').load('page2.html')", 250); // try diff. values
        });
    });
});
```

If that does not solves the problem, it would help to see the complete source of page1.html and page2.html.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#link').live('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'ajax_info.txt', 
            dataType : 'text', 
            success: function(data){
                var $response1 = $('<div />').html(data);
                $.ajax({
                   url : 'ajax_info.txt', 
                   dataType : 'text', 
                   success: function(data){
                      responseCombined = $response1.find('p:last').html(data).end().html();
                      $('#content').html(responseCombined);
                   }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id='link'>load</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the success callback of the first request, I tried to load the responseHTML into a temp `<div>` and in the callback of the second request, I searched for the element `p:last` (in your case it will be #content2) and put the response of the second ajax request into it. Finally, put the combined data into `#content`.

For a demo, goto http://w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first and run the above code.

Answer (score 1):

## your main page html

```
<body>
<a href="#" class="link">i load your page</a>
<div id="container-page1">
</div>
</body>
```

## your page1 html

```
<div>
   <p>i'm important text</p>
   <div id="container-page2"></div>
</div>
```

## jquery > version 1.7

I used an event firing because it keeps your javascript flat.  Otherwise you can end up with some deeply nested code if you need to go 3 or 4 ajax calls deeper later on!

if your jQuery is < 1.7, then let me know and I can throw together .delegate / .live equivalents.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on({'click': function(evt) {
        $(evt.data.containerSelector).load(evt.data.page1Url, function(data, status, jqxhr){
            $(this).trigger(evt.data.loadPage2Event);
        });
    },'a.link',{page1Url:'page1.html',
 loadPage2Event:'loadPage2',
 containerSelector:'#container-page1'});

    $("#container-page1",'body').on({'loadPage2':function(evt){
       $(this).load(evt.data.page2Url);
  }},'#container-page2',{page2Url:'page2.html'});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With the latest JQuery, and run on Chrome, Firefox & IE 9, the following works perfectly fine:

**INDEX.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('a.link').live('click', function() {
                $('#content').load('link1.html', function(){
                     $('#content2').load('link2.html');
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <a class="link" href="#">load</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**link1.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is page 1</p>
    <div id="content2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**link2.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page 2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is page 2</p>
</body>
</html>
```

So I'd say that wither you don't have the latest version of jQuery, or that the problem is in something else inside page1 or page2.html

Answer (score 1):

If I am correct, you are trying to load onto the second secontainer, after first container is loaded

Add a simple class on your markup

```
<div id="content" class="toload"></div>
```

&

```
<div id="content2" class="toload"></div>
```

Now, here is the magical jQuery you need

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.link').live('click', function() {
        $('.toload').load('page1.html', function(){
            $(this).removeClass('toload');  //Remove the class so that next time it does not get affected
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: the second content does not exist until the first was loaded.

Comment: @RaphaelD.G, I know, just update the class, where it is present, it will all work out in the end. Just give it a try

Answer (score 1):

your answer works on my chrome, but try to `empty` the content to be sure that you are not having double `#content` elements

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.link').live('click', function() {
        $('#content:first').empty().load('page1.html', function(){
            $('#content2').load('page2.html');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to empty the #content first before you assign new content to it

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('a.link').live('click', function() {
      $('#content').empty();
      $('#content').load('page1.html', function(){
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('a.link').live('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#content').load('page1.html', function(){
       $('#content2').load('page2.html');
   });
});
```

Comment: test yourself -> www.dielecsur.com/index_spa.php and then click for example in **ventas** href option at sitemap at bottom page. there some advertence but I can't understand it

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that there's DOM element in your page1.html which you can quote as a selector in your index.html jQuery.  So here's a layout you could use for page1.html:

```
<div id="content2">//id name changed
   Content
</div>
```

In your index.html, use this jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('a.link').live('click',function(){
        $('#content').load('1.html', function(){
            $('#content2').load('2.html');
        });
    });
});
```

If it's still flickering back and removing the 2.html inside #content2, see if you're clicking the link more than once.  Also, use either FireBug or Chrome's Inspect Element tool to check all the Network transfers to see what's being loaded and what isn't.

Comment: i dont understand the reason why using `<div id='page2'>`

Comment: test yourself -> www.dielecsur.com/index_spa.php and then click for example in **ventas** href option at sitemap at bottom page. there some advertence but I can't understand it

Comment: Encabezados de petición
Accept text/html, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Charset ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language es-es,es;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Connection keep-alive
Cookie PHPSESSID=uhjlefg9ldo5p6fq9pvdu75li3
Host dielecsur.com
Referer http://dielecsur.com/index_spa.php?u=conan
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1
X-Requested-With XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 0):

So here's how I would solve this problem...

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a.link").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
               url:'page1.html',
               success:function(data) {
                   $("#page1").html(data);
               },
               complete:function() {
                   $.ajax({
                      url:'page2.html',
                      success:function(data) {
                         $("#page2").html(data);
                      }
                    });
                }
          });
        });
     });
```

Slightly more code, but using the success and complete callback functions should give a bit more control over when these divs are populated.   In my example, index.html has the 
and page1.html has the  tag - seems to work fine with no wonkiness for me...