# Php output buffering and sleeping

Tags: php, sleep, buffering

Im tring to get php to load a webpage, wait for a minute, and load another page..
Problem is, php does not output the first page before sleeping and outputting the second page to the screen...

Here is my code:

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.paylesstitleloans.com/");
sleep(60);
header("Location: http://www.paylesstitleloans.com/faq.html");
?>
```

Would using function like these help me at all:
ob_start();
ob_flush();

I need the first page to display on the browser before sleeping.. Any help would be great! Thank you. Jason

Answer (score 1):

You need to use something on the client side (Javascript, meta refresh, iFrames) to accomplish this.

Relevant topics:

- [jquery function that load html code into a div and then load other content into div inside html loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394066/jquery-function-that-load-html-code-into-a-div-and-then-load-other-content-into)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot user headers from php after the page has already loaded. But, you can use a meta tag to redirect after a certain amount of time. Please refer to the meta example below.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60;url=http://www.paylesstitleloans.com/faq.html/" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't do that with location in http headers because you only can send it once.
You'll have to use javascript for that with a timeout function.

including this script in first page would do the trick :

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
redirectTime = "60";
redirectURL = "http://www.paylesstitleloans.com/faq.html";
function timedRedirect() {
    setTimeout("location.href = redirectURL;",redirectTime);
}
//   -->
</script>
```

Comment: Javascript would not be advisable. Not everyone uses javascript :(

Comment: I had never heard about this "http-equiv refresh". But as "Refresh is not part of the HTTP standard." (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh), I would still consider javascript as a suitable solution.

Comment: JavaScript is another alternative, but not recommended, because users might have disabled JavaScript in their browsers.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh

Comment: maybe because they don't want to be redirected :)